# update_attributes works locally, but doesn't affect the change when deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a simple rails webservice that exposes a JSON API that allows clients to POST a new record. When the POST is processed, it first creates the referenced record, but also updates some related records at the same time.

```
@foo = Foo.new(foo_params)
if @foo.save
    related_list = Foo.where(:some_id => foo_params[:list])
    related_list.each do |related|
        # <figure out some stuff here>
        related.update_attributes(stuff)
    end

    # debug spew
    @test = Foo.find(a_related_record_id)
    puts @test.as_json

    format.json { render json: @foo.as_json }
end
```

I recognize this is a bad two-phase commit pattern, and it's abusive of the typical REST model, but I inherited this code. I'm going to fix it eventually; this is all part of the "fixing" plan in stages.

This code works perfectly on a local test box. When deployed to Heroku, I put in debug spew that shows the model apparently being updated after update_attributes is called. However, somehow, the model isn't actually updated. When I check on the "related" records afterwards using a webpage, none of them have been updated with the "stuff" changes. I'm quite baffled by this since the debug spew appears to show the record being updated. Any insights?

**Update**

One thing I just noticed as I went back through my debug spew is that the updated_at datetime never changes, even though the field in the record appears to have. You can see from the lines below that the call was made around 8:04:15 UTC. Also, I verified that update_attributes was returning true, so there was no error as far as I could tell.

Before update_attributes is called:

> ←[36m2012-09-20T08:04:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m { "created_at"=>Thu, 20 Sep 2012 00:43:45 UTC +00:00, **"somefield"=>""**, "id"=>2, **"updated_at"=>Thu, 20 Sep 2012 06:22:07 UTC +00:00**}

After update_attributes is called:

> ←[36m2012-09-20T08:04:15+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m { "created_at"=>Thu, 20 Sep 2012 00:43:45 UTC +00:00, **"somefield"=>"10000848364"**, "id"=>2, **"updated_at"=>Thu, 20 Sep 2012 06:22:07 UTC +00:00**}

Comment: Could it be that `stuff` hash includes the old `updated_at` value?

Comment: Good question. No, I checked. The `stuff` hash only contains the `somefield` change and the contents are correct.

Comment: Is there any sort of page-caching going on with the view that renders the updated records?

Comment: No (to the page caching). I verified by checking the database directly, to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much painstaking research, I managed to figure out the source of the issue, and the fix, but I'm not clear *why* this is happening. Still, it's unblocking me for now, and that suffices.

In the code above, within the

```
# <figure out some stuff here>
```

block. There was code that I abstracted out in the original question since I didn't think it was pertinent. Turns out it was. Specifically, there was a line where I was doing a string concatenation:

```
some_string << @foo.somestringfield
```

This one line, for some reason, caused

```
related.update_attributes(stuff)
```

not to save to the database. This was 100% reproducible (trust me, I tested it about 10 times to be sure). The fix was simple:

```
some_string = some_string + @foo.somestringfield
```

That, seriously, fixed the problem. I did not debug deep into the guts of the in-place concatenation within ruby to determine the root cause, but if someone else ever encounters this problem, well, now you know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in general this behavior (`update_attributes` saves on local but not on Heroku) can be troubleshooted by making sure you're not executing a function inside of the call to `update_attributes`.

For me, calling `update_attributes(:heartbeat => Time.now)` worked on local and failed to save on Heroku. Using the answer above, I took a guess and resolved the issue by saving `Time.now` to a variable before calling update_attributes:

```
heartbeat = Time.now
thing.update_attributes(:heartbeat => heartbeat)
```

This code saved properly on Heroku.
This should be a comment, but due to reputation rules, I'm 'answering.'